# Android Bodymovin animation to mp4 video

Tags: android, lottie, bodymovin

In Android, I want to export bodymovin animation as mp4.

I have animation files like this [Lottie Files](https://lottiefiles.com/featured). now I am looking for code in which I can export this animation as mp4

The code I have tried:

```
public void generateFrame(Drawable yourLottieDrawable) {
   drainEncoder(false);

   final Canvas canvas = inputSurface.lockCanvas(null);

    try {
        yourLottieDrawable.draw(canvas);
    } finally {
        inputSurface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: please check it [this](https://engineering.21buttons.com/how-to-generate-videos-using-lottie-in-android-2db6ecceb2a)

Comment: @Dhaiyur i already tried this but i am losing frames.